# Undeprecating tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

When making a DNN regressor and predicting the values by

```
print(list(estimator.predict({"p": np.array([[0.,0.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.],[1.,1.]])})))
```

this is the output of the console:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From "...\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\dnn.py":692: calling BaseEstimator.predict (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with x is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
Instructions for updating:
Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
Example conversion:
  est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
```

So I head into line 692 of `dnn.py` and this is what I find

```
preds = super(DNNRegressor, self).predict(
        x=x,
        input_fn=input_fn,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        outputs=[key],
        as_iterable=as_iterable)
```

So following the advice from the error, and assuming that `super(DNNRegressor, self)` is an `Estimator` I've just did

```
preds = estimator.SKCompat(super(DNNRegressor, self)).predict(...)
```

But doing that I get

```
TypeError: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_fn'
```

that looks like it's not a tensorflow error.

The problem is I don't know how to get rid of the warning (not an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This portion of the [Github tree](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn) is under active development.  I expect this warning message to go away once the Estimator class is moved into `tf.core` which is schedule for version r1.1.  I found the 2017 TensorFlow Dev Summit [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t64ortpgS-E&index=6&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKGc_NBoIhTn2Qhraji53cv) by Martin Wicke to be very informative on the future plans of high level TensorFlow.